# MySQL db connection

Tags: android, mysql, database, logging

I have been searching the web for a connection between my Android simulator and a MySQL db.
I've found that you can't connect directly but can via a web server. The web server will handle my request from my Android.

I found the following code on [Hello Android](http://www.helloandroid.com), but I don't understand. If I run this code on the simulator, nothing happens; the screen stays black.
Where does `Log.i` land, in the Android screen, the error log, or somewhere else?
Can somebody help me with this code?

```
package app.android.ticket;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class fetchData extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  //call the method to run the data retreival
    getServerData();


}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://www.jorisdek.nl/android/getAllPeopleBornAfter.php";

public fetchData() {
    Log.e("fetchData", "Initialized ServerLink ");
}

private void getServerData() {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";

    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+
                            ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+
                            ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")
                    );
            }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Logging](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#logging) messages go in the Log cat. You could also use [LogCat Reader](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.nolanlawson.logcat/CatLog-Logcat-Reader).