# How to get details from mysql database for android?

Tags: android

How can I connect MySQL and Android?
I have MySQL db in remote I want get the values from that database and display those content in Androidlist view. I have tried many web service samples, but I have met some problems.

I have tried this using json and php from this link http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/ , but my app quits

Comment: Please show the exact code you're using and the problem it's giving you. As it is, no one can help you, we don't know what your problem is.

Comment: use ksoap web service to transfer those data from your database to android device, parse that data and store that data in android database

Answer (score 2):

There is no JDBC driver for android / MySQL. So you can't connect to your database as a desktop application or a web server would.

You then have to write a small interface, typically a web server to make your mysql data available, and then write a small android client, usually parsing xml stuff from your server.

That's the way to go, the very big picture, but your question is vast and fuzzy, that's the best answer I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to access mysql database from android.

1. You can access data from web services for [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) lib is good fro that. Click for web services example   [web-services example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)
2. You can also use Http connection or socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

This have been repeatedly in SO,  here a i leave you with some samples

**SO**

- [Connect MySQL database from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316763/connect-mysql-database-from-android)
- [Get data to android app from mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898823/get-data-to-android-app-from-mysql-server)
- [How to connect to a MySQL Database from an Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253127/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-from-an-android-app)
- [android remote database connection trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737227/android-remote-database-connection-trouble)
- [mysql db connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194991/mysql-db-connection)
- [Connect MySQL database from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316763/connect-mysql-database-from-android/4570434#4570434)

And also in other places,

**AndDev**

- [[TUTORIAL] Connecting to MySQL database](http://www.anddev.org/post91169.html#p91169)
- [HELP with a Tutorial for connection using MySql](http://www.anddev.org/post98732.html#p98732)

**More**

But wait there is more :D, on [google](http://www.google.com.ni/#hl=es&source=hp&q=Android+mysql+database&oq=Android+mysql+database&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=595l3787l0l3882l24l19l1l9l9l0l215l1409l0.8.1l9l0&fp=1456c090789d2bd7&biw=1920&bih=951)

[image]